# How to find element's id equal var value?

Tags: jquery

How to find element's id equal variable value?
$('.el'[id="var"]) not work..

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    var current_id = $(this).attr('id'); // console.log(current_id);
    $('.b[id="current_id"]').css({'font-size':'22px'}); // not work
    // console.log($('.b')); get[<div class="b" id="0">0</div> , <div class="b" id="1">1</div> , <div class="b" id="2">2</div>]
}, function(){

});
```

html

```
<div class="a" id="0">0</div>

<div class="b" id="0">0</div>
<div class="b" id="1">1</div>
<div class="b" id="2">2</div>
...
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with same id.If it does then your scrpt wont work.Id must be unique.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Deepu Thanks for reply whodering why you say wont work? it works in my demo page..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
var current_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
$('.b[id="'+current_id+'"]').css({'font-size':'22px'}); 
}, function(){

});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/KFUVq/)